# Spring MVC with angularJS routing

Tags: angularjs, spring, model-view-controller

Hi I am building application using spring MVC where I want to use AngularJS routing, but the way I have developed it that routing is not happening.I don't want build SPA(Single Page Application) but the application which works like in spring after receiving request it will find match controller and will process it

Below is my project structure

[image]

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
window.open('http://localhost:8080/SpringApp/loginPage.do',
        '_top','toolbar=no, location=no, status=yes, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes,resizable=1,width=1000,height=580,left=0,top=0');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <!-- <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file> -->  
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- <context:annotation-config/>   
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pack"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>-->

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
     </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pack" />
    <!--<mvc:resources location="/jsp/**" mapping="/jsp/**" />-->

</beans>
```

IndexController.java

```
package com.pack.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String root() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.pack.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.pack.bean.User;

@Controller("loginController")
public class LoginController {

    static List<User> users = null;
    boolean isExist = false;

    static{
        users = new ArrayList<User>();
        User user = new User();
        user.setLoginId("Yatin");
        user.setUserName("abc");
        users.add(user);
        user = new User();
        user.setLoginId("admin");
        user.setUserName("admin");
        users.add(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="loginPage", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(@ModelAttribute("login") User user) {
        System.out.println(users);
        return "login"; 
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "loginUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addContact(@ModelAttribute("login")User user,HttpServletRequest req,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){

        for(User u : users){

            if(user.getLoginId().toLowerCase().equals(u.getLoginId().toLowerCase()) && user.getUserName().equals(u.getUserName())){
                isExist = true;
                System.out.println("Login : isExist : "+isExist);
            }           
        }

        System.out.println("LoginId : "+user.getLoginId()+" : Password : "+user.getUserName());
        if((user.getLoginId()!= null && !"".equals(user.getLoginId())) && (user.getUserName()!= null && !"".equals(user.getUserName())) && isExist == true){
            req.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
            //return "redirect:addContact.do";
            return "redirect:dashBoard.do";
        }else if((user.getLoginId()== "") && (user.getUserName()== "")){
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("loginMessage","Login and Password cannot be blank.");
            return "redirect:loginPage.do";
        }else{
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("loginMessage","Invalid login credentials.Please login again.");
            return "redirect:loginPage.do";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLogOut(HttpServletRequest req){
        System.out.println(".....logging out");
        req.getSession(false).invalidate();
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

MyController.java

```
package com.pack.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.pack.bean.Contact;
import com.pack.service.MyService;

@Controller("myController")
@SessionAttributes
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    MyService ms;

    @Autowired
    Contact contact;

    @RequestMapping(value="dashBoard", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showDash() {
        return "homeApp";   
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="addContact", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(@ModelAttribute("contact") Contact cntc) {
        return "addContact";    
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="contact", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addCustomer(@ModelAttribute("contact") Contact cntc,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        System.out.println("You entered "+cntc.getUserName()+" and "+cntc.getContactNo());
        contact = ms.setMyContact(cntc);
        System.out.println("after set : "+contact.getUserName()+" : and : "+contact.getContactNo());        

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("contact", cntc);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message","Added successfully.");

        return "redirect:contacts.do";  
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="contacts", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer") Contact cntc) {
        System.out.println("cntc:" + cntc.getUserName());
        return "contact";
    }

    public Contact _getContact(Contact ct){
        return ms.getMyContact(ct);     
    }
}
```

Contact.java

```
package com.pack.bean;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Contact {

    private String userName;
    private String contactNo;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }
    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact [userName=" + userName + ", contactNo=" + contactNo
                + "]";
    }
}
```

User.java

```
package com.pack.bean;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("session")
public class User {

    private String loginId;
    private String userName;

    public String getLoginId() {
        return loginId;
    }

    public void setLoginId(String loginId) {
        this.loginId = loginId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [loginId=" + loginId + ", userName=" + userName + "]";
    }
}
```

MyService.java

```
package com.pack.service;

import com.pack.bean.Contact;

public interface MyService {

    Contact getMyContact(Contact ct);
    Contact setMyContact(Contact c);
}
```

MyServiceImpl.java

```
package com.pack.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.pack.bean.Contact;
import com.pack.dao.MyDao;

@Service("myService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    MyDao md;

    @Override
    public Contact getMyContact(Contact ct) {
        return md.getMyContact(ct);     
    }

    @Override
    public Contact setMyContact(Contact c) {
        return md.setMyContact(c);
    }

}
```

MyDao.java

```
package com.pack.dao;

import com.pack.bean.Contact;

public interface MyDao {
    Contact getMyContact(Contact c);
    Contact setMyContact(Contact c);
}
```

MyDaoImpl.java

```
package com.pack.dao;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.pack.bean.Contact;

@Repository("myDao")
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {

    @Override
    public Contact getMyContact(Contact ct) {

        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.setUserName(ct.getUserName());
        c.setContactNo(ct.getContactNo());
        return c;       
    }

    @Override
    public Contact setMyContact(Contact c) {
        return getMyContact(c);
    }
}
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form action="loginUser.do" method="post" commandName="login">
Login : <form:input path="loginId"/></br>
Password : <form:password path="userName"/></br>
<input type="submit" value="Login"></br>
${loginMessage}
</form:form>
</br>
</body>
</html>
```

homeApp.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>AngularJS Routing</title>

    </head>
    <body>
      <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="StudentController">
        <div ng-view></div>
      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28//angular-route.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

      mainApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'jsp/dashBoard.jsp',
                controller: 'StudentController'
            })
            .when('/viewStudents', {
                templateUrl: 'jsp/addContact.jsp',
                controller: 'StudentController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home'
            });
      });

      mainApp.controller('StudentController', function($scope) {
        $scope.students = [
            {name: 'Mark Waugh', city:'New York'},
            {name: 'Steve Jonathan', city:'London'},
            {name: 'John Marcus', city:'Paris'}
        ];

        $scope.message = "Click on the hyper link to view the students list.";
      });     
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

dashBoard.jsp

```
<div>
    <h2> Welcome </h2>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <a href="#/viewStudents"> View Students List</a>
</div>
```

addContact.jsp

```
<div>
    <h2> View Students </h2>
    Search:
    <br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    <br/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="student in students | filter:name">{{student.name}} , {{student.city}}</li>
    </ul>

    <a href="#/home"> Back</a>
</div>
```

The issue I am facing, I am not able to route between pages which kept under WEB-INF/jsp/

How to use angularJS routing with Spring MVC, I want to rendered different page attached with each controller request.

Please help.
Please guide me where I will have to make changes in above code.